# docker with modified python modules?

Tags: python, docker

I use docker to use multiple python packages via pip install on a VM. Now, I have modified for my purpose two files within those modules. How can I make docker to look at those files instead on the files installed via pip in dockerfile? I suppose, just copying the modified python files to the working dir will not work?

Comment: I think that you think this is enough information to work with but its pretty vague. Can you give us more information on what your doing here?

Comment: When I run in Docker file pip install like:

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

and I modified some files within the packages of requirements, I ask myself how to supply those files that those are used and not those installed from pip

Comment: If I understand correctly, this (https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds) might be something that could help. In one image you could install all your modules, then overwrite some, then COPY them into a fresh image?

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 01:**

Step 1:

Install the required modules via RUN pip install as before

Step 2:

Remove the files that you will add in next step

Step 3:

Copy the modified files from your current directory to the correct path in the image.

Done

**Approach 02**

```
Install everything in Dockerfile as before
Build the image
Run a container from that image
Exec into the container and modify the files
Get out of the conainer and commit the container as new image
```

Comment: Many Thanks, but could you elaborate this more as I am a docker beginner. How would I do Step2 and 3 since I even don't know where docker "installs" these files? And your approach 2 I don't understand.